# OpenCV uncompressed raw video file - what format?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, ffmpeg, raw

I'm trying to save an uncompressed raw video file given some frames with OpenCV. Going trough the [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/dd/d9e/classcv_1_1VideoWriter.html#ac3478f6257454209fa99249cc03a5c59), I can read:

> If FFMPEG is enabled, using `codec=0`; `fps=0`; you can create an uncompressed (raw) video file.

OpenCV seems to have FFMPEG enabled; indeed, `cv::getBuildInformation()` gives me the following:

```
  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES (prebuilt binaries)
      avcodec:                   YES (58.134.100)
      avformat:                  YES (58.76.100)
      avutil:                    YES (56.70.100)
      swscale:                   YES (5.9.100)
      avresample:                YES (4.0.0)
    GStreamer:                   NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            YES
      DXVA:                      YES
```

I'm trying the following:

```
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
void testLosslessWriter()
{
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0, cv::CAP_DSHOW);

    int w = int(cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH));
    int h = int(cap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));

    cv::VideoWriter writerUncompressed("test_raw", 0, 0, cv::Size(w, h));

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) Error: Bad argument (CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): test_raw) in cv::icvExtractPattern, file C:\workspace\libs\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp, line 253
[ERROR:0@0.325] global cap.cpp:597 cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.7.0-dev) C:\workspace\libs\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): test_raw in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

The same happens if I try, just for example, other formats as "test_raw.avi", "test_raw.mp4" or (made up) "test_raw.raw".

What's the right way to use the documentation hint?

### Edit 1

Following Rotem answer, the problem was in fact with `fps=0`; the issue above got solved with '.avi' and fourcc "RGBA".
However:

```
// Error returned:
// OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x00000000/'????' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'rawvideo / raw video'
cv::VideoWriter writerUncompressed("test_raw.rgb", 0, 1, cv::Size(w, h));  // the same for test_raw.yuv
```

The output file is written (and it is not zero-sized), but when I try to open it back with `VideoCapture` using `CAP_FFMPEG` or `CAP_ANY` API preferences (actually using python, but that should be irrelevant) I got `[IMGUTILS @ 0000003dbc7edaf0] Picture size 0x0 is invalid` and no frame is read

Comment: please calculate the bitrate of your uncompressed video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to FFmpeg conventions, raw video file extension supposed to be `.yuv`.
The frame rate supposed to be positive (the exact value doesn't matter for raw video - `0` is probably reserved for images).
Replace `cv::VideoWriter writerUncompressed("test_raw", 0, 0, cv::Size(w, h));` with:

```c++
cv::VideoWriter writerUncompressed("test_raw.yuv", 0, 1, cv::Size(w, h));
```

Note that other extensions may also work (like `.rgb`), but most file extensions are not going to work.

---

The raw video "pixel format" is `yuv420p`.
Example for converting the `test_raw.yuv` to MP4 file using FFmpeg CLI:

`ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -video_size 640x480 -pixel_format yuv420p -r 1 -i test_raw.yuv -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p test_raw.mp4`

---

Code sample that writes 10 synthetic video frames to `test_raw.yuv`:

```c++
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

int main()
{
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int n_frames = 10;

    //For raw video, use yuv file extension
    cv::VideoWriter writerUncompressed("test_raw.rgb", 0, 1, cv::Size(width, height));  //Set FPS to 1 (0 may not be supported).

    //Generate 10 synthetic video frames:
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < n_frames; i++)
    {
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
        img = cv::Scalar(60, 60, 60);

        cv::putText(img, std::to_string(i + 1), cv::Point(width / 2 - 100 * (int)(std::to_string(i + 1).length()), height / 2 + 100), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 10, cv::Scalar(30, 255, 30), 20);  // Green number

        //cv::imshow("img", img);cv::waitKey(100);
        writerUncompressed.write(img);
    }

    writerUncompressed.release();

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note:
For uncompressed AVI video, we may use `fourcc('R', 'G', 'B', 'A')`:

```c++
cv::VideoWriter writerUncompressed("test_uncompressed.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('R', 'G', 'B', 'A'), 1, cv::Size(width, height));
```

If you find `fourcc` for `BGR` pixel format (3 bytes per pixel instead of 4), please let me know.

---

### Update:

**Reading raw video frames using `cv::VideoCapture`:**

Reading pure raw video, without video file container is problematic, since the raw video file doesn't have any information about resolution, and pixel format.

We may write the raw video with [NUT video container](https://ffmpeg.org/nut.html).
Use video file name with `.nut` extension.

---

Code sample for writing and reading with NUT video container:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>

int main()
{
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;
    int n_frames = 10;

    //For raw video, use nut file extension (use NUT file container)
    cv::VideoWriter writerUncompressed("test_raw.nut", 0, 1, cv::Size(width, height));  //Set FPS to 1

    //Generate 10 synthetic video frames - write yuv420p raw video to NUT file container:
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < n_frames; i++)
    {
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
        img = cv::Scalar(60, 60, 60);
        cv::putText(img, std::to_string(i + 1), cv::Point(width / 2 - 100 * (int)(std::to_string(i + 1).length()), height / 2 + 100), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 10, cv::Scalar(30, 255, 30), 20);  // Green number

        writerUncompressed.write(img);
    }

    writerUncompressed.release();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //Read the raw video frames from the test_raw.nut
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    cv::VideoCapture cap("test_raw.nut");
    cv::Mat frame;

    while (true)
    {
        cap >> frame; //Read the video frame. OpenCV automatically converts the frame to BGR pixel format.
        
        if (frame.empty())
        {
            break; //Break the loop when there are no more frames to capture
        }

        imshow("frame", frame);
        cv::waitKey(100);
    }

    cap.release();
    cv::destroyAllWindows();
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    return 0;
}
```

---

Note:
There may be a way to read pure raw video file using cv::VideoCapture, but if it's not possible, we may simply open the file as binary file, and use `fread` to `img.data`.
The pixel format is yuv420p, and cv::Mat size is going to be `640x720`.
Use `cv::cvtColor` with `cv::COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420` for converting to BGR.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Since comment would be limited, I've reported in an edit the issue with implementing what you suggested.

Comment: `test_raw.rgb` is working in my machine, but you better try `test_raw.yuv`. I am using Windows 10 and OpenCV version `OpenCV 4.7.0-dev` (Version control:  `4.7.0-1-g9208dcb07c`). I am using the pre-built version from [GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/download/4.7.0/opencv-4.7.0-windows.exe).

Comment: I am also getting the error message: `OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x00000000/'????' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'rawvideo / raw video'`, but the `test_raw.yuv` is created (the size is `4,608,000` = 640*480*1.5). Reading the file using `VideoCapture` is a different story... (I never tried that).

Comment: I think the meaning of "raw" should be less strict here. OP probably just wants to avoid lossy compression. literal raw bitstreams are of little use to most people that _say_ "raw". nor are most people aware of color spaces, or conversion.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, actually I'm trying, along with uncompressed raw, also lossy and lossless compression. For the specific application, I might need all the three, depending on a series of factors. I'm actually not interested in how and in what format exactly the raw bitstream is written to file, so long as I'll have a compatible way to read it back from the other end.

Comment: @Rotem, I was using VideoCapture because, somehow, I will have the necessity to open the file recorded. However, as far as I need, the raw .avi works so I'm happy; I'll dig into .yuv further to see how to handle the issue.
Thanks to both for the support.

Comment: @Buzz I added an example for reading raw video frames using cv::VideoCapture (using NUT video container). I didn't emphasize it in my answer, and I hope you are aware to the fact that the conversion from RGB to YUV420 is not lossless, due to color subsampling.

Comment: test_raw.rgb and test_raw.yuv are both not working for me. Using Windows 10 and OpenCV 4.6.0.
Only working coded is fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'); on my setup.

Comment: @ThierryCampiche I can't guess the cause for the problem. In case you have built OpenCV from sources, try installing (and using) the pre-build OpenCV version from EXE instead. It could also be a path issue. Make sure `opencv_videoio_ffmpeg460_64.dll` is in the execution "search path" (or `opencv_videoio_msmf460_64d.dll` for debug configuration).